# Text Editor using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor

I am looking for a text editor in my webpage. Actually my requirements are uploading image, dragging and resizing images, changing canvas background color,text background color, dragging text, changing font and fontsize. I have seen so many editors like nicedit, yuiedit and lot of jquery editors. None of them have dragging text by mouse and changing background canvas.

Is there any editor available with above mentioned options.?

Comment: Why does it matter that that an editor uses jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo). It allows you to drag text and change background colors. It also has a [jQuery plugin](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery) wrapper.